# Highlight nvim tree directory that contains file I found with telescope

Tags: neovim, plugin-telescope

Is there a way to highlight a directory of a found file?

For example I look for a specific file with telescope and when I open it, my nvim-tree is updated and shows me parent directory?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to the file in current buffer by using `:NvimTreeFindFile`.
To do this automatically upon opening the file in telescope, you need to "overload" the open action of Telescope (called select_default, on  - carriage return) to run NvimTreeFindFile command just after you open the file. You can do so by using [transform_mod](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/blob/master/lua/telescope/actions/init.lua):

In ~/.config/nvim/init.vim put this configuration:

```
lua << EOF

local transform_mod = require('telescope.actions.mt').transform_mod
local actions = require('telescope.actions')
local mod = {}
mod.open_in_nvim_tree = function(prompt_bufnr)
    local cur_win = vim.api.nvim_get_current_win()
    vim.cmd("NvimTreeFindFile")
    vim.api.nvim_set_current_win(cur_win)
end

mod = transform_mod(mod)

require("telescope").setup{
    defaults = {
        mappings = {
            i = {
                ["<CR>"] = actions.select_default + mod.open_in_nvim_tree,
            },
            n = {
                ["<CR>"] = actions.select_default + mod.open_in_nvim_tree,
            },
        },
    },
}
EOF
```